# The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, int

Tags: java

here is my code

```
public class InterestCalculatorDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer n=20;
        Integer p=50000;
        Double r=0.5;
        //Formula A= p(1+r)^n
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Double x=p*(1+r);
            Double value=x^i;
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
}
```

when i run it its give this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, int

    at com.priyan.exam2010.InterestCalculatorDemo.main(InterestCalculatorDemo.java:12)
```

Please help me to sort out this issue

thanks

Comment: I recognize the discrete capitalization formula, which you are calculating wrong. You should first do `Math.pow(1 + r, i);`, then multiply for `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is not the power operator,  but bitwise exclusive or (xor), which is defined only for integer types.

You should use [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) instead:

```
double value = Math.pow(x, i);
```

Comment: thanks dear friend.
then its give hexa values.how to get those as double values

Comment: What do you mean by "hexa"?

Comment: 1.7797851562500002E29
1.3348388671875E34 these type Hexadecimal numbers

Comment: @PriyanChngd These are not hexadecimal numbers, they are floating-point values in scientific notation. Neither ^ nor Math.pow() gives hex values. There is no such thing as a hex value. There are only hex representations, and you aren't using them. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's just scientific notation. Your result is that big because you are calculating the wrong interest formula. See the comment I left on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong operator anyway. There is no exponentiation operator in Java. ^ is an XOR operator.

You need Math.pow().

Answer (score 0):

As it explains..

```
 The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) Double, int
```

In Java, the `^` operator performs *XOR*, and is not the power operator. The `^` operator can only work between two `int` values.

Much like the billion other answers,

```
Math.pow(x, i);
```

will solve your problems.

**In Future**...

You would have saved yourself a lot of trouble by simply *reading the error message*.

```
The operator ^ is undefined
```

So here, you know that `^` doesn't exist in this context.

```
for the argument type(s) Double, int
```

So now you know that in the context of a `Double` and an `int`, `^` does not exist. You know that `^` does *something*, clearly. So you need to change the *context*.

Comment: thanks dear friend.
then its give hexa values.how to get those as double values

Comment: In this case he needs to change the operator, not the context.

Comment: i need to get numbers like 50000,55000.75,55750.56...etc [not real answer numbers]

Comment: @PriyanChngd Now what is a 'real answer number'? You aren't making any sense.

Comment: @EJP Granted, he was using the wrong operator. But that wasn't *the error*. The error was what was asked about, which is why I spent most of the answer talking about his error message.